# how to influence RH and air presure to resistance of air

Tags: pressure, electrical-resistance, air, humidity

For example higher RH (relative humidity of air) provide lower air electrical resistance. But how I can calculate with this relation?

Moreover air pressure (between 1500 and 500 hpa) can influence air electrical resistance? If yes how I can calculate with this relation?

Moremoreover air temperature (between 0 and 40 C) can influence air electrical resistance? If yes how I can calculate with this relation?

Thanks for any advise, 
kzsolt

Comment: What kind of resistance? Electrical? Or air resistance in the context of free fall etc?

Comment: For pressure, you should Google for the Paschen curve (which seems appropriate on Easter Sunday).

Comment: Sorry, electrical resistance.